# i am using formData for uploading in javascript

Tags: javascript, upload, javascript-objects, multipartform-data, form-data

I am using formData for uploading in javascript.

```
let formdata = new FormData()
formdata.appened("key", "value");

console.log(formdata) // this gives me an empty object
console.log(...formdata) // this give me array of arrays in console
console.log(formdata.get("key")) // this also gives me the output in console
```

My Question is why formdata is empty when i console it without using spread operators or without get() method. why formdata give empty object?

I looked for many places for it's answer but could not get any. if anyone can explain why is this behavior?

Comment: It’s not an empty object. The console just doesn’t format it with any visible contents.

Comment: ok @SebastianSimon but when i console it with spread operator it works fine.
and can you please explain more in what format formdata stored?

Comment: Yes, the spread syntax invokes [`Symbol.iterator`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) which, on the `FormData` prototype, has the same semantics as [`FormData.prototype.entries`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries), which results in an Array. It doesn’t matter how the data is stored internally; all you have to know is how the API is used. You could, for example, try `console.log(Object.fromEntries(formdata));`.

Answer (score 0):

A `FormData` object is simply an array-like **iterable** structure that holds many name-value pairs or potentially an HTML form.

You can get all values by using this approach:

```js
const formData = new FormData()

formData.append('key1', 'value1')
formData.append('key2', 'value2')

const formDataValues = [...formData]

console.log(formDataValues)
```

Read more about iterators you can [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)

Best regards

Comment: OP already showed in their question that they know they can use the spread syntax to show the values. That is not the question though, the question is: _"My Question is why formdata is empty when i console it without using spread operators or without get() method. why formdata give empty object?"_.

Comment: It’s not really array-like; it has multi-set semantics, no numeric indices, and no `length` property. It is just iterable.

Comment: The answer is that it's not a simple object, it's an iterator. Iterator implements special protocol, and you need to call next() method to see the value.

Answer (score 0):

The FormData interface provides a way to easily construct a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and their values.

It has the value stored inside which can be retrieved using proper methods.
For ex:

```
let formdata = new FormData()
formdata.append("a", 1) 
// this will append value. append is a function provided by FormData object.
formData.get("a") // this will print '1'
```

if you want to print all the values then you need to use:

```
a = formdata.values()
// returns an Iterator {}
a.next()
// returns this: {done: false, value: '1'}
a.next()
// then this: {done: false, value: '2'}
a.next()
// then this: {done: true, value: undefined}
```

So use the iterator to go through your values. Use this link to go through more about iterators: [Iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)

Comment: Using `.next` explicitly is the more cumbersome way of using iterators… But still, this doesn’t seem to actually answer the question.

Comment: well, formdata returns an iterator and .next is one of the way to use it. formData is not empty. It is an object containing functions which can be use to get the values. It is not a data structure which provides the value directly like primitive types or arrays.

Comment: I think your comment should be part of the answer.